# WSO2 Mi 4.2.0 Unresolved Requirement Error

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I have newly deployed my wso2-mi-4.2.0 service on Linux RHEL 8.5 server. Once I start my service getting below error.

Java Version : openjdk version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16 LTS

[2024-02-09 00:55:15,731] ERROR {Events.Framework} - FrameworkEvent ERROR org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core [202]
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.hp.hpl.jena.query; version="0.0.0"

Below is my logs stack.

```
TID: [2024-02-09 00:55:11,897]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Overriding files in configuration directory /opt/wso2mi-4.2.0 {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser}
TID: [2024-02-09 00:55:12,043]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Applying configurations with deployment configurations {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser}
[2024-02-09 00:55:15,731] ERROR {Events.Framework} - FrameworkEvent ERROR org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core [202]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.hp.hpl.jena.query; version="0.0.0"

        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

[2024-02-09 00:55:15,732] ERROR {Events.Framework} - FrameworkEvent ERROR org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.odata.endpoint [203]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.odata; version="4.2.0"
    -> Export-Package: org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.odata; bundle-symbolic-name="org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core"; bundle-version="4.2.0"; version="4.2.0"; uses:="com.datastax.driver.core,javax.servlet.http,org.apache.olingo.commons.api.data,org.apache.olingo.commons.api.edm,org.apache.olingo.commons.api.edm.provider,org.apache.olingo.commons.api.http,org.apache.olingo.server.api,org.apache.olingo.server.core,org.apache.olingo.server.core.requests,org.apache.olingo.server.core.responses,org.apache.olingo.server.core.uri.parser,org.jongo,org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core"
       org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core [202]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.hp.hpl.jena.query; version="0.0.0"

        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

[2024-02-09 00:55:16,474] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseHandlersLoader} - Error creating Handler for class name : org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.odata.endpoint.ODataPassThroughHandler java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.odata.endpoint.ODataPassThroughHandler cannot be found by synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseHandlersLoader.createHandler(SynapseHandlersLoader.java:102)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseHandlersLoader.loadHandlers(SynapseHandlersLoader.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.<init>(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:209)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.<init>(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:217)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.<init>(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:224)
        at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.createSynapseEnvironment(Axis2SynapseController.java:384)
        at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:192)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:336)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:151)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:147)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

[2024-02-09 00:55:16,475] FATAL {org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} - Couldn't initialize the ESB... org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error creating Handler for class name : org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.odata.endpoint.ODataPassThroughHandler
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseHandlersLoader.handleException(SynapseHandlersLoader.java:150)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseHandlersLoader.createHandler(SynapseHandlersLoader.java:104)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseHandlersLoader.loadHandlers(SynapseHandlersLoader.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.<init>(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:209)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.<init>(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:217)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.<init>(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:224)
        at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.createSynapseEnvironment(Axis2SynapseController.java:384)
        at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:192)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:336)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:151)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:147)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.odata.endpoint.ODataPassThroughHandler cannot be found by synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseHandlersLoader.createHandler(SynapseHandlersLoader.java:102)
        ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following two properties to the server startup script.

```
-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true \
-Djdk.nio.zipfs.allowDotZipEntry=true \
```

Comment: We have above both the lines, still its throwing us the error.

Comment: Did you check whether your downloaded WSO2 pack is corrupted? Try redownloading or checking the MD5 sum.